# Moving up the barplot or moving down the legend

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am trying to make my barplot as good as possible. I found the problem with the label on `xaxis`. It overlaps with the names of the plots on the chart.

That's the code which I use:

```
tbl_EOD$location_subacon <- gsub("(.*),.*", "\\1", tbl_EOD$location_subacon)

dataToPlot<-table(tbl_EOD$location_subacon)
cols <- c("blue", "red", "orange", "yellow", "purple", "green", "black", "pink", "indianred", "brown") 
par(las=2)
barplot(dataToPlot, col=cols, main="Subcellular localization",
        xlab="Name of compartment",
        ylab="Number of identified proteins",
        cex.names = 0.80)
```

And reproducible example:

```
> dput(dataToPlot)
structure(c(927L, 29L, 155L, 8L, 162L, 178L, 91L, 90L, 666L, 
33L), .Dim = 10L, .Dimnames = structure(list(c("cytosol", "endoplasmic reticulum", 
"extracellular", "golgi", "mitochondrion", "nucleus", "peroxisome", 
"plasma membrane", "plastid", "vacuole")), .Names = ""), class = "table")
```

And the chart:

[image: Chart]

I tried to play with `cex.names` but I don't find it so helpful in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the margin size using `par(mai)`, then leave the x-axis label blank, and then add in the axis label using `mtext` at an appropriate distance (i.e., `line`) from the plot. Something like:

```
par(mai=c(2,1,1,1))
barplot(dataToPlot, col=cols, main="Subcellular localization",
        xlab="",
        ylab="Number of identified proteins",
        cex.names = 0.80) 
mtext("Name of compartment", side=1, line = 7, las=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I can ask in the same question instead of creating a new one. Can you tell me how I can add the exact numbers of identified proteins on the top of each plot ?

Comment: @ShaxiLiver Take a look at the `text` function.